# SWIFT Delegate finishedWithAuth

Tags: iphone, oauth, swift

i am new to swift and tried to implement Google Auth with GPPSignInDelegate. I get the sign in dialog but the delegate methods:
- didDisconnectWithError
- finishedWithAuth
are never called. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I tried to translate it so swift and it looks ok, but something is not working. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GPPSignInDelegate {


var kClientID = "XYZ"

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var gppsloginButton: GPPSignInButton!
var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;
    signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]

    signIn.delegate = self
    signIn.authenticate()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication,  error: NSError ) -> Void{
    debugPrintln("TEST")
}

func didDisconnectWithError ( error: NSError) -> Void{
   debugPrintln("TEST2")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add the GPPURLHandler from your app delegate's URL handler in your AppDelegate.swift .

> This handler will properly handle the URL that your application receives at the end of the authentication process.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation:annotation)
}
```

Comment: Even if you haven't missed it, make sure that you have the correct types in the declaration. I had String instead of NSString? for the sourceApplication, using the correct type fixed it for me... unsurprisingly.